# Pygame error: mixer system not initialized

Tags: python, audio, pygame

I've just started a little game project and I'm trying to make it play a sound everytime a bullet is fired but i keep getting the same error:

```
pygame.error: mixer system not initialized
```

I don't get what I've done wrong, so here is my code:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

theClock = pygame.time.Clock()

sound = pygame.mixer.Sound("bullet.mp3")
```

....

```
if event.type == KEYDOWN:
    if event.key == K_SPACE and shot_count == 0:
        sound.play()
        shot_y = h-50
        shot_x = x
    elif event.type == K_SPACE and shot_count == 1:
        shot_y_2 = h-50
        shot_x_2 = x
    print(h, ' ', shot_y, shot_count)
if event.type == KEYUP:
    if event.key == K_SPACE and shot_count == 0:
        resetShot = 0 
    elif event.type == K_SPACE and shot_count == 1:
        resetShot = 0
```

Answer (score 15):

You need to `pygame.init()` before using mixer/sound objects.

According to [documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.Sound), you should use OGG or WAV sound files.

Comment: ok i dont get the error anymore but it doesn't play any sound

Answer (score 4):

I was looking [here](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html) and found out that `pygame` only loads OGG ang uncompressed WAV files.
Another issue is you forgot to initialize the `pygame.mixer` module.

```
pygame.mixer.init()
```

is the most simple way to initialize the `pygame.mixer` module.
For more info, go to the previous link.

Comment: I am having the same problpem I loaded my wave file I pygame.mixer.init() but I keep getting this error  No audio device found

Comment: Try pygame.init() instead of pygame.mixer.init()

Answer (score 1):

I was making a Tetris game before two weeks and I had the same problem!
What I did is inserting this before playing the sound and it worked.

```
pygame.mixer.init(44100, -16,2,2048)
```

Try it yourself and see if it works! I hope that helped

Answer (score 0):

## This is enough

```py
import pygame as pg
from pygame import mixer

pg.init()

#...
mixer.music.load('sounds/bgsound.mp3')

mixer.music.play(-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had encountered the same error on the same project when using pycharm on my linux system.

Simple workaround is to run the sript in the python shell or from the IDLE(pretty much the same).

If you're a linux user like me(I use Ubuntu), simply open the folder containing the script in the terminal and run the script using python, like so:

```
python3 Space_Invaders.py
```

And it should run without any errors. I tried to run the code without initialising the mixer using the python IDLE and encountered no errors there either.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same error on the project. I am using Ubuntu. Do the below things,

Install the pygame and mixer as a Root user.
Run the program as a normal user.

```
# pip3 install pygame
# pip3 install mixer

Run the command
$ python3 Space_game.py
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame import mixer

theClock = pygame.time.Clock()
#mixer setup audio config and sound var not use
sound = mixer.init(44100, -16,2,2048)
#load mixer sound file and sound var use
sound = mixer.Sound("bullet.mp3")

if event.type == KEYDOWN:
    if event.key == K_SPACE and shot_count == 0:
        sound.play()
        shot_y = h-50
        shot_x = x
    elif event.type == K_SPACE and shot_count == 1:
        shot_y_2 = h-50
        shot_x_2 = x
    print(h, ' ', shot_y, shot_count)
if event.type == KEYUP:
    if event.key == K_SPACE and shot_count == 0:
        resetShot = 0 
    elif event.type == K_SPACE and shot_count == 1:
        resetShot = 0
```

and try this option

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame import mixer

theClock = pygame.time.Clock()


if event.type == KEYDOWN:
    if event.key == K_SPACE and shot_count == 0:
        #mixer setup audio config and sound var not use
        sound = mixer.init(44100, -16,2,2048)
        #load mixer sound file and sound var use
        sound = mixer.Sound("bullet.mp3")
        sound.play()
        shot_y = h-50
        shot_x = x
    elif event.type == K_SPACE and shot_count == 1:
        shot_y_2 = h-50
        shot_x_2 = x
    print(h, ' ', shot_y, shot_count)
if event.type == KEYUP:
    if event.key == K_SPACE and shot_count == 0:
        resetShot = 0 
    elif event.type == K_SPACE and shot_count == 1:
        resetShot = 0
```

Comment: Hi, it's better to explain why and how your code addresses the question. Please read [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)