# How do I add background music to my python game

Tags: python, pygame

I have been trying different methods of adding background music to my game, but none of them works the way I want it to.
I the music to play throughout the gameplay.

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pygame
from pygame.locals import *  # noqa
import sys
import random



class FlappyBird:
def __init__(self):
    self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 708))
    self.bird = pygame.Rect(65, 50, 50, 50)
    self.background = pygame.image.load("assets/background1.png").convert()
    self.birdSprites = 
[pygame.image.load("assets/superman.png").convert_alpha(),

pygame.image.load("assets/superman.png").convert_alpha(),
                        pygame.image.load("assets/supermangrayed.png")]
    self.wallUp = pygame.image.load("assets/s_purple.png").convert_alpha() # 
Top of the screen
    self.wallDown = pygame.image.load("assets/cloud.png").convert_alpha() # 
Bottom of the screen
    self.gap = 25   # Gap between the clouds and the building
    self.wallx = 400
    self.birdY = 25
    self.jump = 1
    self.jumpSpeed = 10
    self.gravity = 10
    self.dead = False
    self.sprite = 0
    self.counter = 0
    self.offset = random.randint(-110, 110)
    # I haven't used this variable yet
    self.sound = path.join(path.dirname(__file__), 'assets')


def updateWalls(self):
    self.wallx -= 2
    if self.wallx < -80:
        self.wallx = 400
        self.counter += 1
        self.offset = random.randint(-50, 50)


def birdUpdate(self):
    if self.jump:
        self.jumpSpeed -= 0.5
        self.birdY -= self.jumpSpeed
        self.jump -= 1
    else:
        self.birdY += self.gravity
        self.gravity += 0.1
    self.bird[1] = self.birdY
    upRect = pygame.Rect(self.wallx,
                         360 + self.gap - self.offset + 10,
                         self.wallUp.get_width() - 10,
                         self.wallUp.get_height())
    downRect = pygame.Rect(self.wallx,
                           0 - self.gap - self.offset - 5,
                           self.wallDown.get_width() - 10,
                           self.wallDown.get_height())
    if upRect.colliderect(self.bird):
        self.dead = True
    if downRect.colliderect(self.bird):
        self.dead = True
    if not 0 < self.bird[1] < 720:
        self.bird[1] = 50
        self.birdY = 50
        self.dead = False
        self.counter = 0
        self.wallx = 400
        self.offset = random.randint(-110, 110)
        self.gravity = 3

def run(self):
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    pygame.font.init()
    font = pygame.font.SysFont("calibri", 50)
    while True:
        clock.tick(60)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
            if (event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN or event.type == 
pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN) and not self.dead:
                self.jump = 10
                self.gravity = 4.5
                self.jumpSpeed = 10.5

        self.screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
        self.screen.blit(self.background, (0, 0))
        self.screen.blit(self.wallUp,
                         (self.wallx, 300 + self.gap - self.offset))
        self.screen.blit(self.wallDown,
                         (self.wallx, 1 - self.gap - self.offset))
        self.screen.blit(font.render(str(self.counter),
                                     -1,
                                     (255, 255, 255)),
                         (200, 50))
        if self.dead:
            self.sprite = 2
        elif self.jump:
            self.sprite = 1
        self.screen.blit(self.birdSprites[self.sprite], (50, self.birdY))
        if not self.dead:
            self.sprite = 0
        self.updateWalls()
        self.birdUpdate()
        pygame.display.update()

if __name__ == "__main__":
FlappyBird().run()
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you tried using https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html ? If so, what problems did you run into? (As that seems to be the intended way to add background music.)

Answer (score 5):

**Rule of thumb:  Check documentation before Stack Overflow.**

https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html

Use `pygame.mixer.init()` to initialize the mixer.

Use `pygame.mixer.music.load("file")` to load music into the mixer.

Use `pygame.mixer.music.play(loops, start)` to play the music loaded into the mixer.

ETC.

Just read the documentation, that's what it is there for!

Answer (score 2):

Please try  [pygame.mixer](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html)

```
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load("music.mp3") 
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1,0.0)
```

Comment: I have added these two lines of code to the run function and it says "error: mixer system is not initialized"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22227684/pygame-error-mixer-system-not-initialized